# Dynamically generated link in an email template

Tags: email, merge-field

I have a regular salesforce email template that Im trying to setup to include a link based on the users contact id

something like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/{!Contact.Id}/

The issue is that for whatever reason the link thats clickable in gmail is just the

http://www.mydomain.com part, it leaves the contact id off the link?

any ideas why that might be happening and what i can do to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use merge fields in the "link" modal.  Just write out the text you want to be a link, select it and click the "link" button.  In the URL you can paste a URL that includes merge fields just like `http://www.mydomain.com/{!Contact.Id}`.

Works like a charm, should have tried it sooner but I guess i just assumed it wouldn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the merge field `{!Contact.Link}` which will generate a link to the contact and dynamically fill the server instance URL:

Used in an email template, the merge field resolved to (example):

```
https://cs81.salesforce.com/00326000007e97E
```

This also works for other objects, standard as well as custom. In the merge fields list when you are making an email template, it is referred to as `Detail Link`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Visualforce email template then you can use merge field "Detail Link" in HTML email templates as 
`{!Case.Link}`

But if you are using Visualforce email template it's not going to work.
In this case use below code:

```
{!LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_300, FIND('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_300))+'/'+relatedto.Id}
```

Comment: There is extra +'/' so if anyone is using above link then make sure to remove it

Comment: Avesh - where is extra link?

Comment: +'/'+ this one is extra in the link I have to remove this when pasting the link